# Adding tags to images in RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm trying to add tags to the Image model in RefineryCMS (trying on 1.0.8 and 2.0.4), have added attr_accessible :tag_list, required acts-as-taggable and setup the views, but the problem is that the tags only save when editing/updating a previously uploaded image - not when uploading for first time, even though it uses the same form...

Any ideas?

It happens on every version of rails and Refinery I have tried...

The tags are going through in the post when looking at logs, just not saving...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and eventually find the cause of the extra-attributes (in your case the :tag_list) not being saved on new image upload.

If you look at [`::Refinery::ImageController`](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/images/app/controllers/refinery/admin/images_controller.rb) you'll see that the create action actyally create the image with :

```
unless params[:image].present? and params[:image][:image].is_a?(Array)
    @images << (@image = ::Refinery::Image.create(params[:image]))
else
    params[:image][:image].each do |image|
        @images << (@image = ::Refinery::Image.create(:image => image))
    end
end
```

`params[:image][:image]` is an Array when multiple multiple file uploed is enabled (by default it is). But then the action only use take the array values when creating the images, ignoring the other params.

I quickly write the below work-around that allow to save the other params on multiple image upload :

```
unless params[:image].present? and params[:image][:image].is_a?(Array)
    @images << (@image = ::Refinery::Image.create(params[:image]))
else
    images_params = params[:image].dup
    images_params.delete(:image)
    params[:image][:image].each do |image|
        @images << (@image = ::Refinery::Image.create({:image => image}.merge(images_params)))
    end
```

end

It's probably not the most elegant solution bu it does the trick.

To use it in your app, you'll have to create a decorator for the `::Refinery::ImageController` to copy and edit the create action in it. (see 'Extending a Controller' in [Refinery's Guides](http://refinerycms.com/guides/extending-controllers-and-models-with-decorators))